# rEFInd does not find Windows 7

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, refind

I recently installed Kali Linux to enable me to dual boot between Kali and Windows 7. I had to install Kali in UEFI mode, because that was the only thing that worked. Windows 7 however, is not installed in UEFI mode. Because of this I can't boot Windows from the UEFI GRUB loader. To fix this I installed rEFInd as suggested by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/851948/628749). My problem is that rEFInd does not detect my windows loader on /dev/sda1. I have uncommented the `scanfor` line in `refind.conf` and added `hdbios` as one of the options without any success. I also uncommented `uefi_deep_legacy_scan` although that shouldn't be necessary since everything is on the same disk (only different partitions). I have also tried manually adding the Windows loader to the list, but it doesn't even appear as an option when I boot (I probably did not add it correctly).

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Does anyone know how I manually can add it to the list? Or is my Windows loader broken? If so, what can I do then? (I don't have any installation CD or anything like that for Windows)

Comment: Refind isn't for BIOS mode installs, do yourself a favor and don't mix uefi and bios. Convert your mbr to gpt and 'repair' your Windows bootloader (i.e. make it uefi) with the rescue media. You can generate a repair USB within Windows.

Comment: @jiggunjer Ok, but I am currently unable to boot windows, how can I do this?

Comment: Assuming sda1 is your 100MB windows7 boot partition, set that as your target in the uefi boot manager settings. These settings are accessible during boot, if not then boot into Linux and use `efibootmgr` to configure.

Comment: @jiggunjer I tried this, but when I selected my custom entry nothing happened and GRUB just reloaded.

Comment: Is GRUB higher on the list than sda1? Make sure you add the BIOS mode switch: just saying sda1 will fail because it will try UEFI and fail to read NTFS.